# how select combobox and input to database

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

I made a combobox whose data is taken from jenis_makanan table. from the combobox the selection will be entered into makanan table. i don't know where is wrong, how input the ComboBox option into the database?

this is controller for input data

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Gambar;
use App\JenisMkn;
use App\cmb;
use Input;
class MakananController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $makanan = Gambar::all();
        return view('makanan', ['makanan'=>$makanan]);
    }
    public function input()
    {
        $jenis = JenisMkn::select('id_jenis','jenis_makanan')->get();
        return view('upload_gambar',['jenis'=>$jenis]);
    }
    public function proses(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request,[
            'file'=>'required|file|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
            'makanan'=>'required',
            'jenis'=>'required',
        ]);

        $file = $request->file('file');
        $nama_file = time()."_".$file->getClientOriginalName();

        //nama folder tempat file diupload
        $tujuan_upload = 'image_file';
        $file->move($tujuan_upload,$nama_file);

        Gambar::create([
            'file' =>$nama_file,
            'makanan'=>$request->nama_makanan,
            'jenis'=>$request->kode_jenis,
        ])->post();
        return redirect('/makanan');
    }
}
```

this is html

```
            <form action="{{Route('proses')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <b>File Gambar</b>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="file" name="file">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <b>Nama Makanan</b>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="text" name="makanan">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <b>Jenis Makanan</b>
                    <br/>
                    <select name="cmb" id="" class="form control input-sm">
                        @foreach ($jenis as $j)
                            <option value="{{$j->id_jenis}}">{{$j->jenis_makanan}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary">
            </form>
```

the output said the jenis field is required

Comment: Can you post your HTML code as well?

Comment: You are sending data `$request->kode_jenis` as kode_jenis and validating for `jenis`, so it would generate that `jenis` field is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Controller You Used Validator

```
 $this->validate($request,[
            'file'=>'required|file|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
            'makanan'=>'required',
            'jenis'=>'required',
        ]);
```

here jenis is required..But In Your Blade File No Input Field name is jenis.So, Change the input field name to jenis

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <b>File Gambar</b>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="file" name="file">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <b>Nama Makanan</b>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="text" name="makanan">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <b>Jenis Makanan</b>
                    <br/>
                    <select name="jenis" id="" class="form control input-sm">
                        @foreach ($jenis as $j)
                            <option value="{{$j->id_jenis}}">{{$j->jenis_makanan}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
```

In Controller,

```
Gambar::create([
            'file' =>$nama_file,
            'makanan'=>$request->makanan,
            'jenis'=>$request->jenis,
        ]);
```

Comment: thank's but know an error sql sintaks SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'makanan' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `makanan` (`file`, `makanan`, `jenis`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1568872588_13962.jpg, Cake, 3, 2019-09-19 05:56:28, 2019-09-19 05:56:28))

Comment: can you give me migration file??

Comment: how to send migration file ? I never send in here

Comment: just copy the migration file & paste it

Comment: <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class Makanan extends Migration
{
   
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('makanan', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id_makanan');
            $table->string('file');
            $table->string('nama_makanan');
            $table->integer('kode_jenis');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('makanan');
    }
}

Comment: In Controller,Gambar::create([
            'file' =>$nama_file,
            'nama_makanan'=>$request->makanan,
            'kode_jenis'=>$request->jenis,
        ]);